# Foundation error/fade flashes with ngAnimate before ngModel loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, zurb-foundation

I've got a directive, with a field in it. The field is being passed a $scope with the model in it.

The field is ng-required="true".

Because there is a split second where the data isn't loaded into the template, there is an unsightly flash of red error text around the field.

I've tried template caching, changing the class colour, but none of it happens at the right time. What we've done in the interim is remove ng-animate. This stops the delay and flash and fade. However, this is a set back as animations would be swell in other places.

From here I will ask the concrete question:
As ngAnimate is injected in the app.js, is there a way to disable injection at a per element/controller/directive level?

As far as I know, injection cascades when it is included in the global app.js.

Comment: You could avoid displaying the error while the field is pristine, or avoid displaying the field, or the directive itself, until the data is ready. ng-show and ng-if are your friends. For a more concrete answer, post a more concrete question.

Comment: Agreed with @JBNizet - I've handled these types of "flashes" before using an ng-show/hide on a container element, only making children visible when the app is "ready". Post some code for more details

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is set a flag to signal when the content has finished loading, and I don't show any content until that's been set to true.

On your controller

```
$scope.finishedLoading = function() {
    ... whatever logic you need to figure out if all your data is loaded ...
    return $scope.myData != null;
}
```

Then in some part of your template that wraps the fields you want initially hidden:

```
<div ng-hide="finishedLoading">Please wait...</div>
<div ng-show="finishedLoading">
    .. your page content here ..
</div>
```